# Get posts with ajax

Tags: ajax

I want to get posts with ajax by click function.

**Jquery**

```
$(".get-posts").click(function(){

  $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',  
    data: { action : 'get_ajax_posts' },  
    success: function(){  
       // ???
    }
  });  
});
```

**Php**

```
function get_ajax_posts() {
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('products'),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'posts_per_page' => 40,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'cat' => 1,
    );

    // The Query
    $ajaxposts = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $ajaxposts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $ajaxposts->have_posts() ) {
            $ajaxposts->the_post();
                get_template_part('products');
        }
    } else {
        get_template_part('none');
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_posts', 'get_ajax_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_posts', 'get_ajax_posts');
```

I'm blocked here.

Comment: read this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. and then use `.done(`... and read what is in `data`.

Comment: And what's the question?? PS. You don't have to do `wp_reset_postdata()` in AJAX callbacks, but you do have to do `die` in there.

Comment: How i can print template_part? With echo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Option 1

The simple way - return all the posts in `JSON` format and loop through them in JavaScript

**PHP:**

```
function get_ajax_posts() {
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('products'),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'posts_per_page' => 40,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'cat' => 1,
    );

    // The Query
    $ajaxposts = get_posts( $args ); // changed to get_posts from wp_query, because `get_posts` returns an array

    echo json_encode( $ajaxposts );

    exit; // exit ajax call(or it will return useless information to the response)
}

// Fire AJAX action for both logged in and non-logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_posts', 'get_ajax_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_posts', 'get_ajax_posts');
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',
    dataType: "json", // add data type
    data: { action : 'get_ajax_posts' },
    success: function( response ) {
        $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
            console.log( key, value ); // that's the posts data.
        } );
    }
});
```

---

### Option 2

Get HTML content and print it to the screen.

**PHP:**

```
function get_ajax_posts() {
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('products'),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'posts_per_page' => 40,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'cat' => 1,
    );

    // The Query
    $ajaxposts = new WP_Query( $args );

    $response = '';

    // The Query
    if ( $ajaxposts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $ajaxposts->have_posts() ) {
            $ajaxposts->the_post();
            $response .= get_template_part('products');
        }
    } else {
        $response .= get_template_part('none');
    }

    echo $response;

    exit; // leave ajax call
}

// Fire AJAX action for both logged in and non-logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_posts', 'get_ajax_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_posts', 'get_ajax_posts');
```

**JavaScript:**

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',
        dataType: "html", // add data type
        data: { action : 'get_ajax_posts' },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response );

            $( '.posts-area' ).html( response ); 
        }
    });
```

In the second example, change the `.posts-area` selector to the one you want to print in.

The `console.log` is just that you will be able to see the returning information from the AJAX call in the console. You should remove it after you finished.

Comment: Furthermore, in case you don't want to mix PHP and Javascript languages to same files (Which you shouldn't), you can pass urls for ajax requests by wp_localize_script (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: in option 1 there is an erroneous `new` in the line `$ajaxposts = new get_posts( $args );` it should read `$ajaxposts = get_posts( $args );`

Comment: @jopfre updated.